# Ruby throwing stack level too deep error on version 2.5.5-p157 exclusively

Tags: ruby

I am getting this error when starting up,
can someone please help me with this?

```
Message from application: stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
  /apps/oracle/redmine/redmine-4.0.3-3-Dev/apps/redmine/htdocs/plugins/redmine_agile/lib/redmine_agile/patches/compatibility/application_controller_patch.rb:18:in `before_action'
```

Here's the file:

```
  module Patches
    module ApplicationControllerPatch
      def self.included(base) # :nodoc:
        base.extend(ClassMethods)
        base.class_eval do
          unloadable # Send unloadable so it will not be unloaded in development
        end
      end

      module ClassMethods
        def before_action(*filters, &block)
          before_action(*filters, &block)
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

I am getting the error with this version of Ruby:

```
Ruby version 2.5.5-p157 (2019-03-15) [x86_64-linux]
```

But working fine with:

```
Ruby version 2.5.3-p105 (2018-10-18) [x64-mingw32]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your patched version of the `before_action` method, you are calling the xact same method again. Thus, each time your patched `before_action` is called, you are entering an endless loop, eventually leading to a stack overflow.

The Ruby versions are likely a red herring (that is, they are not actually related to the issue at hand). If the issue doesn't occur on one version, it is likely because some subtle ordering differences when loading the code.

The main issue however is still that you are calling the same method again in a recursive loop. Fix that and your error will vanish.

From the surrounding code, it appears that this is a compatibility layer to make code targeted at older Rails versions compatible with a newer Rails version. Here, the (older) method `before_filter` is likely intended to be aliased to the newer `before_alias` method. You might want to check this with the author of the Redmine plugin.

Comment: If you found the answer to be helpful, please consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).